# Stuck on creating a dynamic Time Table in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was working on a personal project where I tried to make a dynamic Timetable for my Tuition Centre that can directly sort out the Timetable based on different batches as well as a personalized Timetable for each faculty member for ease of access. This is the link to a copy of the same spreadsheet on Google Sheets, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10DtMwfNzEcnTRt0D873Pz0VX2-f7UD8L6DuHSTWIZHw/edit?usp=sharing . My vision for this was that the person making the Timetable just needs to allot classes in the "Daily TT" tab and everything else would generate automatically. First, I created the Batchwise TT, and it was a simple enough task of just referencing cells from Daily TT.

The real trouble I faced was in generating the faculty wise TT. The furthest I could get was this formula " =IF($I2 = INDEX($B$2:$B$44,MATCH("PHY(MS)",C$2:C$44,0),1),INDEX($A$2:$A$44,MATCH("PHY(MS)",C$2:C$44,0),1),"-")"(which can be seen in cell J2 of class with Faculty tab). In this formula the only problem I am facing is that if there are multiple instances of PHY(MS) value in the column, it only returns the first value every time and thus all other values become null which is incorrect. I tried solving the problem using queries as well as Search function, but they returned worse results. Is there a better way to do this or an easy modification to above formula to make it work more accurately?

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=index(let(Λ,'Daily TT'!$A$1:$A$55,Σ,reduce(tocol(,1),filter(row(Λ),right(Λ,3)="ing"),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(
 chooserows(Λ,sequence(3,1,c+2,1))&"|"&upper(left(chooserows(Λ,sequence(3,1,c,0)),3))&"|"&chooserows('Daily TT'!$B$1:$F$55,sequence(3,1,c+1,0))&"|"&chooserows('Daily TT'!$B$1:$F$55,sequence(3,1,c+2,1)))))),Γ,split(tocol(Σ),"|"),
 map(I2:I7,lambda(Σ,bycol(J1:O1,lambda(Λ,join(char(10),ifna(filter(index(Γ,,3),index(Γ,,1)=Σ,index(Γ,,2)=Λ,index(Γ,,4)=P1)))))))))
```

- *the formula directly picks the value(s) from `Daily TT` tab*
- ***Clear** all the cells within the range **J2:O7**(`Class with faculty TT` tab) prior to applying this formula within `Cell_J2`*
- *Just **copy the cell formula from J2 now** and paste it in `J10`, `J18`, `J26`, `J34` and so on... for the other subjects to populate automatically*

[image]

Comment: Wow that worked like a charm, couldn't ask for anything more. If it's not too much trouble could I ask you to give me a little detailed rundown of how the formula works, because I tried to understand it but couldn't make head or tail of it. Thanks again for the help.